# Dissapearing/changing private information in facebook messenger

Tags: facebook, botframework, bots, chatbot, messenger

I am a new chatbot developer.

I recently saw a Bank's facebook page that lets you check your account balance.
The chatbot shows you the account balance then after 10 seconds it changes the content of the message to "This message has been hidden for your privacy"

Does anyone have any idea how to do this / replicate this feature?

edit : Here's a video sample of the feature
https://youtu.be/_bDSZGir0kw

Comment: I don’t think that is something you can implement yourself, this has to be some functionality explicitly provided by Facebook for such purposes. Guess this could probably be part of the “message tag” functionality, maybe `PERSONAL_FINANCE_UPDATE` or something like that. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/message-tags

Comment: Are you using the botframework? Does it do this within the chat box, or as a [WebView](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview) popup?

Comment: @misorude the tags don't seem to do anything special at the front end. I'll edit my question to add a video sample of what I saw.

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT Yes we're using botframework. They do it at facebook messenger channel not through webchat.

Comment: @Belfaux I tried out the tags and I don't believe they serve that purpose. Your video says it's "unavailable". Maybe need to make it public? Botframework isn't able to update facebook activities and I don't see anything in the Facebook docs that seem to make it possible. I'm relatively sure they use a webview of some kind.

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT sorry about the video link. I have updated it to unlisted and should work now.

Comment: @Belfaux In the video, are they using Facebook messenger? Botframework can't update previous messages and I can't find *anything* in the Messenger API that allows for it, either.

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT 
We recorded that using Facebook messenger for iPhone but it works on Android FB messenger as well.

Strangely, desktop web Facebook won't show the balance at all. It just says "we couldn't retrieve your account balance"

Yeah, I figured the bot won't be directly able to do that. It's so strange since there's no documentation on this kind of feature. Do you think they're using some hacky workaround for this?

Comment: @Belfaux I looked again through the Facebook documentation and played around with the non-Botframework Facebook API and I have no idea how the bank was able to do that. Sorry :(